# phrase "enter into"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Regards to the phrase "enter into" being used in the two sentences, does it express the meanings accurately?

> Many contemporary undergraduates who just enter into society are still lack of necessary skills and experience.
>
> When students enter into secondary schools, they will have more opportunities to get involved into natural science studies.

Comment: "contemporary undergraduates" probably doesn't mean what you think it does. It's a slightly stilted way of saying "modern undergraduates", as opposed to, say, undergraduates in the 1950s. From the context of the sentence, it sounds like perhaps you mean people who have completed an undergraduate degree course recently, in which case what you want is "recent graduates".

Comment: I actually want to say comparing with those undergraduates in old ages, maybe in 1950s, the recent graduates still have the same issue as before. So the education system issue is STILL not resolved completely. Is it still accurate to use the word "recent"?

Comment: In which case, to make it really clear (which it might already be from context, I haven't seen the rest of the document that your quote comes from), I'd go with making it absolutely clear with a sentence like "Undergraduates in the modern Educational system". That will avoid any ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

In both cases, the word "into" is unnecessary (not *wrong*, but *unnecessary*).  In other words, you could say either:

> Many contemporary undergraduates who enter into society...

or:

> Many contemporary undergraduates who enter society

because, in both of these cases, the verb *enter* already implies entering *into* something.

A few other notes about your sentences:

- I would change "contemporary" to either "new" or "recent" (*contemporary* seems to read awkwardly there)
- "who just enter into society" might be better said as "entering into society"
- "are still lack *of*" should be "are still *lacking*"
- "secondary schools" can be written as "secondary school" (even though it's more than one school building, it's considered a single level of education)
- we generally get involved "with", not "into"

So, folding all those changes into your sentences would yield:

> Many recent undergraduates entering into society still lack necessary skills and experience.
>
> When students enter secondary school, they will have more opportunities to get involved with natural science studies.

Comment: It's worth noting that when *enter* is used figuratively it isn't always interchangable with *enter into*. For example you can *enter into a contract*, but you can't really *enter a contract* (or can you? It sounds wrong to me). Although I can't think of an obvious rule, because you *enter into negotiations* and also *enter negotiations*. You also can't go the other way. For example you can *enter a bid*, but you can't *enter into a bid*.

Comment: @Matt: True statement; nice catch. I've made a change to my answer so that it doesn't create the false impression that one can always drop the _into_ from the phrasal verb _enter into_. (Those are great examples, by the way; I'm glad you entered them into the discussion.)